# Reading file on macOS gives FileNotFound even though file exists ( and has permission )

Tags: java, macos, file, javafx, macos-sonoma

I have a javafx app that allows selecting an image and displaying it or lets you select a folder, read images inside and display them.
In either case, it works fine on Windows, but when run on macOS it does not work and throws a  `FileNotFoundException`.
Here is the code to read it:

```java
String path = Paths.get(pathToFile).toUri().toString()
```

That line gives me the path

`file:///Users/userName/Downloads/untitled%20folder/image.png`

But then the exception says

```
file:/Users/username/Downloads/untitled%20folder/image.png (No such file or directory)
```

I tried to remove the space from the folder, give 0777 permission to all files. It just does not read it.
I want to add that the file path is obtained from the javaFX file chooser and it is not put there manually.

The complete code is pretty much this:

```java
String path = Paths.get(loadedFilePath).toUri().toString();
File file = new File(path);
System.out.println(file.exists());
com.drew.metadata.Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new File(path));
```

The exception is thrown in the `readMetadata()` method but already the `file.exists()` returns false.

Comment: Form the exception's message it looks like you're missing two `/`s after the `file:`. Can you share the code that produces this error?

Comment: I wanna point out that the path produced by the exception is different from the path that i print before creating the File(). So in the process of creating the file object, a couple of `/` get lost on the way. Im gonna post a better code example if you need

Comment: Yes, please post a [mcve]

Comment: Done, there is not much to the code other than the file chooser in another class, but that just returns me the path string u see above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `File` class works with local paths, not URIs, so going through `Paths` just to get a URI and then convert it to a string and use it with a `File` won't work, as you've seen.

Instead, you can use `Paths` to get a `File` object directly:

```java
File file = Paths.get(loadedFilePath).toFile();
```